# div inside ul prevents selecting first child li selector

Tags: html, css

I am working in a CMS. first-child selector not working as there is a div inside the ul. When i remove the div in console, first-child selector applies. I cant change the DOM nor use JS. So what would be the solution. Thanks in advance.

```css
ul.tab-list li:first-child img{
     max-width: 145px;
     height: 59px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab-list">
  <div></div>
  <li class=" tab-list-element">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>
  </li>
  <div></div>
  <li class=" tab-list-element">
    <a href="#">
      Link Text
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is not so clear what exactly do you want. Please be clear and specific. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Why can't you change this? This is _invalid_ HTML to begin with.

Comment: _"So what would be the solution."_ - maybe to simply target the _second_ child instead then ...?

Comment: first-of-type instead of first-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the `<img>` inside the `<li>` that is the subsequent sibling of the `<div>` that is the first child of a `<ul>`:

```css
ul > div:first-child + li img {
  // ...
}
```